# How to get the scores of each feature from sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-analysis, feature-selection

I am trying to get the scores of all the features of my data set.

```
file_data = numpy.genfromtxt(input_file)
y = file_data[:,-1]
X = file_data[:,0:-1]

x_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all').fit_transform(X,y)
```

Before the first row of X had the "Feature names" in string format but I was getting "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')"  error. So, now X contains only the data and y contains the target values(1,-1).

How can I get the score of each feature from SelectKBest(trying to use Uni-variate feature selection)?

thanks

Comment: Looks like you can just do `x_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')` followed by `x_new.scores_`

Comment: @Ryan You mean like this: x_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all').fit_transform(X,y)
print(x_new.scores_)? It gives me "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'scores_'" error. I apologize, I am kinda new to Python.

Comment: `x_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')` then `x_new.fit_transform(X,y)` then `print x_new.scores_`

Comment: @Ryan That worked! Thanks! Why didn't it work when I was using  x_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all').fit_transform(X,y)?

Comment: The `scores_` are accessible from the `SelectKBest` object. When you `fit_transform` the object that is returned is a numpy array

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. Unfortunately, the voting up option is not appearing currently. I will vote your comment up asap.

Comment: @Ryan Using x_new as a variable name for an estimator object (which is _not_ a new version of X) makes your explanation confusing. Maybe just call it selector? The OP was using x_new to refer to the transformed X.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution**

You just have to do something like this.

```
file_data = numpy.genfromtxt(input_file)
y = file_data[:,-1]
X = file_data[:,0:-1]

selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all').fit(X,y)
x_new = selector.transform(X) # not needed to get the score
scores = selector.scores_
```

**Your problem**

When you use directly `.fit_transform(features, target)`, the *selector* is not stored and you are returning the *selected features*. However, the scores is an attribute of the *selector*. In order to get it, you have to use `.fit(features, target)`. Once you have your *selector* fitted, you can get the *selected features* by calling `selector.transform(features)`, as you can see in the code avobe.

As I commented in the code, you don't need to have transformed the features to get the score. Just with fitting them is enough.

**Links**

- [Documentation about SelectKBest in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html)
- [Example in the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection)